# MySQL / MariaDB: Historization - How do it better

Tags: mysql, timestamp, data-warehouse, mariadb

I have exports of person data which I would like to import into a table considering historization. 
I wrote single sql-steps but two questions arises:
1. There is a step where I got a unexpected date
2: I would like to avoid manually submitting some steps and using stored procedure

The tables are:

**Table to be filled considering historization:**

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id           INTEGER      DEFAULT NULL
, name         VARCHAR(50)  DEFAULT NULL
, effective_dt DATE         DEFAULT NULL
, expiry_dt    DATE         DEFAULT NULL
);
```

**Table with person data to be imported:**

```
CREATE TABLE person_stg (
  id        INTEGER     DEFAULT NULL
, name      VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
, export_dt DATE        DEFAULT NULL
, import_flag  TINYINT      DEFAULT 0
);

-- Several exports which has to be imported
INSERT INTO person_stg (id, name, export_dt) VALUES 
  (1,'Jonn'  , '2000-01-01')
, (2,'Marry' , '2000-01-01')
, (1,'John'  , '2000-01-05')
, (2,'Marry' , '2000-01-06')
, (2,'Mary'  , '2000-01-10')
, (3,'Samuel', '2000-01-10')
, (2,'Maria' , '2000-01-15')
;
```

The following first step (1) populates the table *person* with the first state of the person:

```
INSERT INTO person
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.export_dt, '9999-12-31' expiry_dt
FROM person_stg a
LEFT JOIN person_stg b 
ON a.id = b.id
   AND a.export_dt > b.export_dt
WHERE b.id IS NULL
;
SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY id, effective_dt;

+----+--------+--------------+------------+
| id |  name  | effective_dt | expiry_dt  |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | Jonn   | 2000-01-01   | 9999-12-31 |
|  2 | Marry  | 2000-01-01   | 9999-12-31 |
|  3 | Samuel | 2000-01-10   | 9999-12-31 |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
```

Step (2) changes the expiry date:

```
-- (2) Update expiry_dt where changes happened
UPDATE 
  person     a
, person_stg b
SET a.expiry_dt = SUBDATE(b.export_dt,1)
WHERE a.id = b.id
      AND a.name <> b.name
      AND a.expiry_dt = '9999-12-31'
      AND b.export_dt = (SELECT MIN(b.export_dt)
                         FROM person_stg c
                         WHERE b.id = c.id
                               AND c.import_flag = 0
                         )
;
SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY id, effective_dt;

+----+--------+--------------+------------+
| id |  name  | effective_dt | expiry_dt  |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | Jonn   | 2000-01-01   | 2000-01-04 |
|  2 | Marry  | 2000-01-01   | 2000-01-09 |
|  3 | Samuel | 2000-01-10   | 9999-12-31 |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
```

The third step (3) inserts the second status of person data:

```
-- (3) Insert new exports which has changes
INSERT INTO person
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.export_dt, '9999-12-31' expiry_dt
FROM person_stg a
INNER JOIN person b
ON a.id = b.id
   AND b.expiry_dt = SUBDATE(a.export_dt,1)
   AND a.export_dt > b.effective_dt
   AND a.import_flag = 0
;
SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY id, effective_dt;


+----+--------+--------------+------------+
| id |  name  | effective_dt | expiry_dt  |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | Jonn   | 2000-01-01   | 2000-01-04 |
|  1 | John   | 2000-01-05   | 9999-12-31 |
|  2 | Marry  | 2000-01-01   | 2000-01-09 |
|  2 | Mary   | 2000-01-10   | 9999-12-31 |
|  3 | Samuel | 2000-01-10   | 9999-12-31 |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
```

And the last step (4) defines on *person_stg* which record was inserted:

```
-- (4) Define imported records
UPDATE 
  person_stg a
, person     b
SET import_flag = 1
WHERE a.id = b.id
      AND a.export_dt = b.effective_dt
;
```

So far, so good. If I repeat step (2) I got the following table:

```
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
| id |  name  | effective_dt | expiry_dt  |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | Jonn   | 2000-01-01   | 2000-01-04 |
|  1 | John   | 2000-01-05   | 9999-12-31 |
|  2 | Marry  | 2000-01-01   | 2000-01-09 |
|  2 | Mary   | 2000-01-10   | 1999-12-31 |   <--- ??? Should be 2000-01-14
|  3 | Samuel | 2000-01-10   | 9999-12-31 |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
```

Mary/2000-01-10 got expiry_dt 1999-12-31 instead of 2000-01-14. I don't understand how this can happened.
So, my questions are:

(1a) Why this update of the expiry date gives this strange date?

(1b) Is there maybe a better code then (2)?

(2) How can I repeat steps (2) until (4) automatically?     I need only some hints for a stored procedure. 
    -- (4) Define imported records
    UPDATE 
      person_stg a
    , person     b
    SET import_flag = 1
    WHERE a.id = b.id
          AND a.export_dt = b.effective_dt
    ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using cursor which I never used before. First I made a stored procedure (SP)  sp_add_record which update, insert new status or insert a new element given id and export_dt from patient_stg. This stored procedure was then used using SP with cursor (curs_add_records):

```
CALL curs_add_records();
SELECT * FROM person;
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
| id |  name  | effective_dt | expiry_dt  |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | Jonn   | 2000-01-01   | 2000-01-04 |
|  2 | Marry  | 2000-01-01   | 2000-01-09 |
|  1 | John   | 2000-01-05   | 9999-12-31 |
|  2 | Mary   | 2000-01-10   | 2000-01-14 |
|  3 | Samuel | 2000-01-10   | 9999-12-31 |
|  2 | Maria  | 2000-01-15   | 9999-12-31 |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
```

The advantage of this procedure is that I can load table with the same code independently if it is an inital load (population load) or incremental.
Literatur I used:
Djoni Damrawikarte: Dimensional Data Warehousing with MySQL (DWH issues)
Ben Forta: MariaDB Crash Course (SP issues)

What follows are the SP I used.

PS: Was it appropriate to answer to my own question?

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_add_record //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_add_record(
         IN p_id        INTEGER
       , IN p_export_dt DATE
       ) 
BEGIN
    -- Change expiry_dt
    UPDATE 
      person     p
    , person_stg s
    SET p.expiry_dt = SUBDATE(p_export_dt,1)
    WHERE p.id = s.id
          AND p.id = p_id
          AND s.export_dt = p_export_dt
          AND p.effective_dt <= p_export_dt
          AND ( p.name <> s.name )
          AND p.expiry_dt = '9999-12-31'

    ;

    -- Add new status
    INSERT INTO person
    SELECT s.id, s.name, s.export_dt, '9999-12-31' expiry_dt
    FROM 
      person     p
    , person_stg s  
    WHERE p.id = s.id
          AND p.id = p_id
          AND s.export_dt = p_export_dt
          AND ( p.name <> s.name )
          -- does a entry exists with new expiry_dt?
          AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM person p2
                  WHERE p2.id = p.id
                        AND p.expiry_dt = SUBDATE(p_export_dt,1)
                      )
          -- entry with open expiry_dt not should not exist
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                          FROM person p3
                      WHERE p3.id = p.id
                                AND p3.expiry_dt = '9999-12-31'
                          )
     ;
     -- Add new id
     INSERT INTO person 
     SELECT s.id, s.name, s.export_dt, '9999-12-31' expiry_dt
     FROM person_stg s
     WHERE s.export_dt = p_export_dt
           AND s.id = p_id
           -- Add new id from stage if it does not exist in person
           AND s.id NOT IN (SELECT p3.id
                            FROM person p3
                            WHERE p3.id = s.id
                            AND p3.expiry_dt = '9999-12-31'
                           )
     ;  
END
//
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS curs_add_records //
CREATE PROCEDURE curs_add_records()
BEGIN 
  -- Local variables
  DECLARE done        BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE p_id        INTEGER;
  DECLARE p_export_dt DATE;

  -- Cursor
  DECLARE c1 CURSOR 
  FOR
  SELECT id, export_dt
  FROM person_stg
  ORDER BY export_dt, id
  ;

  -- Declare continue handler
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;

  -- Open cursor
  OPEN c1;

  -- Loop through all rows
  REPEAT
    -- Get record
    FETCH c1 INTO p_id, p_export_dt;

    -- Call add record procedure
    CALL sp_add_record(p_id,p_export_dt);

  -- End of loop
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;

  -- Close cursor
  CLOSE c1;

END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do, you don't need a multi-step process.  You are just looking for the "end date" for each record.  Here is a method that uses correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT p.*, export_dt as effdate,
       COALESCE((SELECT export_dt - interval 1 day
                 FROM person_stg p2
                 WHERE p2.id = p.id AND
                       p2.export_dt > p.export_dt
                 ORDER BY p2.export_dt
                 LIMIT 1
                ), '9999-12-31') as enddate
FROM person_stg p;
```

You can also do something using variables.

I'm not sure if this answers your question, because it replaces the whole process with a simpler query.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I didn't know COALESCE. I suppose you forgot to add `LIMIT 1` after `ORDER BY p2.export`. There are two reasons why this simple code does not fit my purpose: (1) The redundant status (Marry) and (2) if there are already entries in _person_ the records in _person_ has to be updated. Nevertheless  your code help me to write a shorter code. I will try to cope with (1) and (2). (Maybe you have an idea why expiry_dt gets 1999-12-31 in my version?)

Comment: @giordano . . . Yes, I forget the `limit 1`.